# Spring OAuth Authorization Server Requires Scope

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

We're currently using the Spring OAuth Authorization Server but currently do not use the "scope" parameter from the OAuth specification. This has been a bit of a pain point as the Spring OAuth Authorization Server requires that scope be explicitly required when requesting an authorization code.

From **DefaultOAuth2RequestValidator**:

```
if (requestScopes.isEmpty()) {
    throw new InvalidScopeException("Empty scope (either the client or the user is not allowed the requested scopes)");
}
```

This however goes directly against the OAuth 2.0 specification:

```
 4.1.1.  Authorization Request

    The client constructs the request URI by adding the following   
 parameters to the query component of the authorization endpoint URI   
 using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format, per Appendix B:

    response_type
          REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "code".

    client_id
          REQUIRED.  The client identifier as described in Section 2.2.

    redirect_uri
          OPTIONAL.  As described in Section 3.1.2.

    scope
          OPTIONAL.  The scope of the access request as described by
          Section 3.3.

    state
          RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
          state between the request and callback.  The authorization
          server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
          to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
          cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.
```

Is there an explicit reason why the Spring Authorization Server does this? I know that I can replace the validator with my own but I'm curious as to why this is the default in case I'm missing any understanding other than it being this way for legacy reasons.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

For those looking for an alternative implementation that follows the specification, here is mine. It simply checks that if the client is restricted to certain scopes, only then the requested scope is required and that the requested scope must be in the list of assigned client scopes. If the client has no assigned scopes, this implementation assumes they are allowed use of any scope (same assumption that is made for resources). Not quite sure yet the implications of this or if it's genuinely correct. Please let me know if it is not.

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidScopeException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.TokenRequest;

public class OAuth2RequestValidator
    implements org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2RequestValidator {

  @Override
  public void validateScope(final AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest,
      final ClientDetails client)
      throws InvalidScopeException {
    this.validateScope(authorizationRequest.getScope(), client.getScope());
  }

  @Override
  public void validateScope(final TokenRequest tokenRequest, final ClientDetails client)
      throws InvalidScopeException {
    this.validateScope(tokenRequest.getScope(), client.getScope());
  }

  private void validateScope(
      final Set<String> requestScopes, 
      final Set<String> clientScopes) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(clientScopes)) {
      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(requestScopes)) {
        throw new InvalidScopeException(
            "Empty scope (either the client or the user is "
              + "not allowed the requested scopes)");
      }

      for (final String scope : requestScopes) {
        if (!clientScopes.contains(scope)) {
          throw new InvalidScopeException("Invalid scope: " + scope, clientScopes);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks to have been already reported as a bug but with no response. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/775

Answer (score 4):

According to the DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory, if no scope is supplied by the client, the scope registered for the client will be used.

**DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory.java**

```
private Set<String> extractScopes(Map<String, String> requestParameters, String clientId) {
    Set<String> scopes = OAuth2Utils.parseParameterList(requestParameters.get(OAuth2Utils.SCOPE));
    ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);

    if ((scopes == null || scopes.isEmpty())) {
        // If no scopes are specified in the incoming data, use the default values registered with the client
        // (the spec allows us to choose between this option and rejecting the request completely, so we'll take the
        // least obnoxious choice as a default).
        scopes = clientDetails.getScope();
    }

    if (checkUserScopes) {
        scopes = checkUserScopes(scopes, clientDetails);
    }
    return scopes;
}
```

So you could configure your client with a *default* scope of "all" or something similar e.g.

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client").secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "client_credentials")
            .scopes("all");
```

Comment: not a bad idea although we're not using scopes at this point so assigning scopes to a client could be viewed as a negative thing as they would potentially have permission to perform actions when scope restriction is added to our application in the future. The question was more around why Spring Security OAuth (at the version I am/was using) is not following the specification.

Comment: I know my comment is too late. But Spring Security Oauth is following the especification according to this fragment of the specification:

" If the client omits the scope parameter when requesting authorization, the authorization server MUST either process the request using a pre-defined default value or fail the request indicating an invalid scope.  The authorization server SHOULD document its scope requirements and default value (if defined)." I agree with @apoplexy